# Apple developer program

Tags: iphone, applications, developer-program

I am 15 year old developer who is currently learning iOS development. I've noticed that you must be at least 18 years old to publish an app. Should I decide to do just that, would it be possible to join the apple developer program even though I am underaged? I wish to use the apps I may submit as a talking point on CVs and applications for higher education.

Comment: You don't mention your country.  In the United States, no because you must be 18 to enter into contract (legal definition).  However a parent or guardian can act on your behalf.  Other countries could vary possibly.

Comment: I live in the UK